# How do I generate a string array in MatLab 2016b?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, runtime-error

I have this small section of code to generate a list of 80 strings with the same format

```
for iter = 1:80
    features(iter) = strcat('test', num2str(iter));
end
```

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

As a result I experience this error as if I was trying to add more than one strings at a time to the array but that seems wrong. It may be to do with the fact that I am using an older version of MATLAB and can't use the string assignment ""? If that is the case what could I do to generate a string array?

If I preallocate the array I receive this error instead

```
features = num2str(zeros(1,80));
```

> In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

Comment: You may want cell arrays here. `features(iter)` is a matrix that can only contain 1 thing, and `test1` is 5 characters. It is not wrong that you are adding  more than one "things", as an you are trying to add an array of chars to a single element. In MATLAB, to define an object that can contain arbitrary stuff on its elements, you want to use `features{iter}`, a cell array. Much slower to do operations on, but works

Comment: That makes sense, never used cell arrays before